# Getting 200 status code instead of 201 or 204

Tags: python, flask, swagger, http-status-codes

I'm using Swagger 2.0 to create the framework of a python-flask backend.
I declared the `POST /image` endpoint as following on the Swagger online Editor:

```
/image:
    post:
      summary: "Description."
      operationId: "image_post"
      consumes:
      - "multipart/form-data"
      parameters:
      - in: "formData"
        name: "upfile"
        description: "The file to upload."
        required: true
        type: "file"
      responses:
        201:
          description: "Ok"
          schema:
            type: "string"
        400:
          description: "bad image"
      x-swagger-router-controller: "swagger_server.controllers.default_controller"
```

After downloading the `python-flask` server, I run it with the command `python -m swagger_server`. When sending a post request through postman I get that the status code is `200` instead of `201`. It also shows `200` on the command line where the server is running.

Any clues if this is a bug? or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to explicitly declare which status code you want to return in your view function; the swagger description is just documentation that your API server doesn't actually care about. Something like this pseudo code:

```
def image():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not is_valid(request.form):
            return jsonify({'errors': [...]}), 400
        # do stuff
        return jsonify({'description': 'created'}), 201
```

Comment: that's a really good catch! I was struggling with this!
Good one, thanks!